# How to grant su access to wheel without asking for password on FreeBSD?

Tags: authentication, freebsd, pam, su

I would like to grant users of the wheel group (other sysadmins) su access without being asked for password.

I know how to do it with pam in linux, but the question now is for FreeBSD. I am not familiar with the syntax for FreeBSD's PAM subsystem. What shall I enter in `/etc/pam.d/su` instead of the default:

```
auth         sufficient   pam_rootok.so   no_warn
auth         sufficient   pam_self.so     no_warn
auth         requisite    pam_group.so    no_warn group=wheel root_only fail_safe ruser
auth         include      system

# account
account      include      system

# session
session      required     pam_permit.so
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some error and trial and the solution for me seems to be like this:

```
# auth
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so           no_warn
auth            sufficient      pam_self.so             no_warn
auth            requisite       pam_group.so            no_warn group=wheel root_only fail_safe ruser
auth            sufficient      pam_group.so            no_warn group=wheel root_only fail_safe ruser
auth            include         system

# account
account         include         system

# session
session         required        pam_permit.so
```

This allows members of the wheel group to su without password, but disallows non-members.
(I think the two line can be consolidated into one, but I did not bother that much.)

Comment: You can just delete or comment out the first line, as it's overruled by the second.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` is configured by sudoers file and `visudo` should be used to edit.

```
visudo -f /usr/local/etc/sudoers
```

Make sure you have this line uncommented:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I do not want to use sudo as it is not in FreeBSD (it is not part of the base system). I know it is possible with PAM and I want to use that.

Comment: OTOH: I corrected the syntax for visudo.